# How to deal with KML3D results in R?

Tags: cluster-analysis, kml, longitudinal

I have done a KML3d in R using longitudinal medical data with 2 outcome-measurements (Eq5d score + oxford score) measured on 3 time-points.

After pre-processing the data, I used the following code to build the model:

```
trajectory_knee <-clusterLongData3d(data, timeInData = list(oxford = c(17, 19, 21), eq5d = c(18, 20, 22)), varNames = c("Oxford score", "Eq5d score"))
kml3d(trajectory_knee, nbClusters = 2:5, nbRedrawing = 4, toPlot = "both")
```

The goal of my KML3d is to predict different clusters containing observations. However, running the KML3D gave me the calinski harabatz plot, while my goal is to:

- obtain the cluster labels generated by the model
- plot the clusters
- use the BIC + plot trajectories to find the optimal numbers of clusters

However, I do not know how to reach the above goals. Is there someone who can help me/ put me in the right direction?

Thanks!

I tried using

- NbClust
- Plotallcriterion
- choice(trajectory)

but none of these give me information about the previously formulated goals...

Answer (score 0):

getClusters() is the appropriate function. See https://www.jstatsoft.org/index.php/jss/article/view/v065i04